# Solr open textbox search

Tags: php, solr, indexing

I have a search textbox where I can write anything. its like "search brand or model" and now i have to get values from two fields that are indexed in solr.

```
brand:audi or model:audi or brand+model:audi
```

Please suggest query that can work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added following line to core schema.xml

```
<copyField source="Make" dest="search"/>
<copyField source="Model" dest="search"/>

<field name="search" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Now I only need following query:

```
search:ford fusion
```

Thanks a lot for letting me know this.

Answer (score 1):

Use copy fields:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields

You can put two fields in one and search in both at the same time